# How to check if user successfully turned bluetooth on after sending an intent to turn bluetooth on intent

Tags: android, bluetooth, onactivityresult

How do you check if someone successfully turned on bluetooth after requesting it to be turned on using the following...

```
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the intent finishes it should call `onActivityResult` in the original activity. You can use this code in the `onActivityResult` to check if the bluetooth was turned on.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //bluetooth was turned on
        }else{
            //bluetooth was not successfully turned on
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void checkBTState() {
        if(btAdapter==null) { 
          errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
        } else {
          if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
          } else {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
          }
        }
      }
```

it's going to check whether the bluetooth is turned on or not, if it's not, its going to start an intent to activate the bluetooth